# Scikit-learn Randomforest with warm_start results (non-broadcastable output ...)

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest

I am trying to build an online random forest classifier. In a for loop I faced an error that I can not find the reason for.

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1, warm_start=True)
```

In the for loop, I am increasing the number of estimators while reading new data.

```
clf.n_estimators = (clf.n_estimators + 1)
clf = clf.fit(data_batch, label_batch)
```

After going through the loop for 3 times, when running the code predict as follows in the loop:

```
predicted = clf.predict(data_batch)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (500,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (500,2)
```

While the data is in shape (500,153) and the label is (500,).

Here is a more complete code:

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1, warm_start=True)
clf = clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
predicted = clf.predict(X_test)

batch_size = 500

for i in xrange(batch_init_size, records, batch_size):
    from_ = (i + 1)
    to_ = (i + batch_size + 1)

    data_batch = data[from_:to_, :]
    label_batch = label[from_:to_]

    predicted = clf.predict(data_batch)

    clf.n_estimators = (clf.n_estimators + 1)
    clf = clf.fit(data_batch, label_batch)
```

Comment: Can you provide reproducible sample data sets. I couldn't reproduce this issue using randomly generated data sets...

Comment: What are the values of `batch_init_size` and `records`? How many classes/labels do you have? Is your data sorted by label?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the error is due to batches having an unequal number of sample classes.
I solved this by using a batch size which will consist of all classes.

Answer (score 2):

I found the cause of the problem:
As the data is imbalanced, there is a high possibility that all the samples from some batches are all from a single class. In such cases in file forest.py is unable to operate on one single dimension and one 2 dimension matrices. Here is the code in forest.py from scikit-learn:

```
def accumulate_prediction(predict, X, out, lock):
    prediction = predict(X, check_input=False)
    with lock:
        if len(out) == 1:
            out[0] += prediction

        else:
            for i in range(len(out)):
                out[i] += prediction[i]
```