# "Warm Start" in combination with new data leads to broadcasting error when predicting with Random Forest

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am trying to train a random forest model with `sklearn`. I have some original data (`x`, `y`) that I use to train the RF initially with.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import numpy as np
x = np.random.rand(30,20)
y = np.round(np.random.rand(30))
rf = RandomForestClassifier()
rf.fit(x,y)
```

Now I get some new data that I want to use to retrain the model, but I want to keep the already existing trees in the `rf` untouched. So I set `warm_start=True` and add additional trees.

```
x_new = np.random.rand(5,20)
y_new = np.round(np.random.rand(5))
rf.n_estimators +=100
rf.warm_start = True
rf.fit(x_new,y_new)
```

So far so good. Everything works.
But when I make predictions I get an error:

```
rf.predict(x)
>>> ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (30,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (30,2)
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Your code runs okay for me on `scikit-learn` v1.1.3 (what I happen to have in front of me). Are you sure this is the only thing you're doing? If so, share the versions of sklearn and numpy.

Comment: I am using v1.2.2 the default on Colab, but I will see if I downgrade will solve the issue

Comment: @MattHall yes it seems to be a problem with the newer version. 
I will see if their github has something on this

Comment: Please consider posting an answer with this finding, regardless if you find anything related in Github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This runs fine for me in colab, with the same sklearn version 1.2.2 mentioned.  I suspect the issue is similar to what was indicated by the now-deleted answer, as well as [Scikit-learn Randomforest with warm_start results (non-broadcastable output ...)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49334063/10495893): one of your datasets (in this case, the `y_new`) doesn't have the same classes.

I tested this by setting `y_new = np.ones(5)` instead of random, and I get the same error; so I think you were just unlucky and got all ones or all zeros with whatever random seed numpy had when you ran this the first time.